# Как осуществлять поиск по id в паттерне mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществлять поиск не в `Code Behind`? есть таблица с книгами, пользователь вводит айди, и программа должна выводить данные о книге на экран. Как это сделать с помощью событий - понятно, а с помощью комманд? Не знаю как передать введённый айди в `MainWindowViewModel.cs` - класс, созданный для реализации логики `MainWindow`. В нем есть комманда `Search`, которая должна пробежаться по списку и найти книгу по айди. Через конструктор пробовала, так он же первым вызывается и выдает ошибки. Возможно, есть какой-то способ? Спасибо заранее.

Кому интересно, благодаря вам, получилилась такая рабочая версия этой задачи:

Хaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox   Height="30" Width="140" x:Name="IdSearchTextBox" Margin="2"></TextBox>
            <Button Name="SearchButton" Content="Search by Id" Height="30" Width="120" Margin="2" 
                    Command="{Binding Search}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=IdSearchTextBox, Path=Text}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Book" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CurrentBook.Nom}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BookTextBox" Margin="5" Width="400"/>
        <Label Content="Auteur" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding CurrentBook.Auteur}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="AuteurTextBox" Margin="5" Width="400"/>
        <Label Content="Description" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding CurrentBook.Description}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DescriptionTextBox" Margin="5" Width="400" Height="150"/>
```

View - ничего нет, кроме инициализации вью модель (Это важно, как оказалось)))

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

ViewModel

```
private Book _currentBook;
private RelayCommand<String> _search;
private ObservableCollection<Book> _books;
public Book CurrentBook
{
    get { return _currentBook; }
    set { _currentBook = value; FirePropertyChanged(); }
}

public RelayCommand<string> Search
{
    get { return _search; } set {  _search = value; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
{
    get { return _books; }
    set { _books = value; FirePropertyChanged(); }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(_conn.Books);
    Search = new RelayCommand<string>(SearchById);
}

public void SearchById(string str)
{
    _id = Convert.ToInt32(str);

    foreach (Book b in Books)
    {
        if (b.Id == Convert.ToInt32(str))
        {
            CurrentBook = b;
        }
    }
 }
```

Желательно, конечно, все это дело try-catch проверить, но так работает, спасибо всем!!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59832/discussion-on-question-by-olga-----id---mvvm).

Comment: Оформите свое решение как ответ ;)